# manifest.json:34:1: an object must end with '}'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have developed an extension and trying to upload it. but it gives error:`manifest.json:34:1: an object must end with '}'.`

Any help will be appreciated. 
here is the content of manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version" :2,
"name": "Text to Speech",
"version" :"1.0.0",
"description" :"Indian language text to speech extension. Developed under TDIL programme by TTS    consortium",
"options_page": "options.html",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": {                    // optional
  "19": "images/text2voice.png"           // optional
},
"default_title": "Indian language TTS",      // optional; shown in tooltip
"default_popup": "popup.html"       // optional
},
"icons": { "16": "images/t2v-48.png",
       "48": "images/t2v-48.png",
      "128": "images/t2v-128.png" },

"background": {
"page": "background.html"
},
 "content_scripts": [
{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"], //content script will be injected in all urls
  "js": ["content_script.js"]
  }
],

"permissions": [ //permitted to access following pages
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*",
"contextMenus",
"tabs"
 ]  
}
```

Comment: You can't have comments in the JSON file.
Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON files. You'll get exact information where the error is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your comments such as `//options` is breaking your json. Please try to put the entire contents of manifest.json validator(http://jsonlint.com) and see the errors.

Comment: The thing is that in developer mode "manifest.json" works perfectly with comments, but this error pops up when you are actually trying to upload it to the store.